# URL parameter not working accept if placed first in order

Tags: php, html, url, parameters

I am trying to hide some elements when accessing the link that contains a certain parameter.
But its works only if the `source=app` is the first in order of all parameters, below is an example of what i mean in order of the parameter.

**URL Parameter URL Working Sample**

https://url.com/app.php?source=app&order_id=274&order_name=phone-black

**URL Parameter URL Not Working Sample**

https://url.com/app.php?order_id=274&order_name=phone-black&source=app

> notice the location source=app parameters in both urls

I used the below code to hide the elements

`<?php if(!isset($_GET['source']) || $_GET['source'] != "app"): ?> HTML <?php endif; ?>`

Is there anything I missed ?

Comment: What actually are you missing? If the HTML text doesn't get displayed then it's actually working, else check if the supply parameters are correct

Comment: @WanPeninsula notice the location source=app parameters in both urls, in the first one it hides it because it's placed first but not in the second one when placed last, i need it to be placed last and work

Comment: I am really missing your **hide** explanations. If I guess right and you don't need it, just ignore it in your code and it should work fine without interruptions.

Comment: @WanPeninsula **hide** means not show certain section in my page based on the url parameter, for example i want to hide (or not show) the website header when the link is access with a source=app parameter

Answer (score 1):

You need to [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) your url to avoid special caracters as `&`:

```
$url = "https://url.com/app.php?".urlencode("source=app&order_id=274&order_name=phone-black");
```

This results in

```
https://url.com/app.php?source%3Dapp%26order_id%3D274%26order_name%3Dphone-black
```

and should work across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to hide parts of your web app based on URL parameters and for this purpose, I hope the following code will be helpful for you:

```
$header = true;

if ( isset( $_GET['source'] ) ) {
    if ( $_GET['source'] == 'app' ) {
        $header = false;
    }
}

if ( $header === true ) {
    // Your HTML
}
```

Now, your code will be work without taking care of the sequence of parameters.